# Mobius: How to set CSharpBackendPortNumber for c# app to talk to Spark Cluster on Linux?

Tags: apache-spark, mobius

I have this very basic code to be run from windows machine connecting to a spark cluster running on a linux virtual box:

```
        string sparkMaster = "spark://192.168.1.193:7077";
        string hdfsURI = "hdfs://192.168.1.193:8020";

        var sparkContext = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().SetAppName("MobiusWordCount").SetMaster(sparkMaster));
```

Followed the instruction as in "getting started page" (installed spark on the windows gateway machine and other prerequisites):

D:\SparkCLR\runtime>scripts\sparkclr-submit.cmd --master spark://192.168.1.193:7077 --total-executor-cores 2 --exe Spar
kCLR.exe "C:\Users\aaa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SparkCLR\SparkCLR\bin\Debug"

Got this error:

SPARKCLR_JAR=spark-clr_2.10-1.6.100.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkCLRSubmitArguments.concatCmdOptions(SparkCLRSubmitArguments.scala:389)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkCLRSubmitArguments.buildCmdOptions(SparkCLRSubmitArguments.scala:492)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkCLRSubmitArguments$.main(SparkCLRSubmitArguments.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkCLRSubmitArguments.main(SparkCLRSubmitArguments.scala)
D:\SparkCLR\runtime>scripts\sparkclr-submit.cmd --verbose --master spark://192.168.1.193:7077 --total-executor-cores 2
--exe SparkCLR.exe "C:\Users\aaa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SparkCLR\SparkCLR\bin\Debug"
SPARKCLR_JAR=spark-clr_2.10-1.6.100.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkCLRSubmitArguments.concatCmdOptions(SparkCLRSubmitArguments.scala:389)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkCLRSubmitArguments.buildCmdOptions(SparkCLRSubmitArguments.scala:492)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkCLRSubmitArguments$.main(SparkCLRSubmitArguments.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkCLRSubmitArguments.main(SparkCLRSubmitArguments.scala)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to compile Mobius code to use it in Linux. You can either get an official [Mobius release](https://github.com/Microsoft/Mobius/releases) and use it or if you have pre-built Mobius binaries (jar file and dlls) from a GitHub repo, you can use them in Windows or Linux irrespective of the platform on which they were built. Mono is a requirement to run Mobius in Linux. If you choose to build Mobius in Linux you need Mono for that as well.

You need to specify CSharpBackendPortNumber and CSharpWorkerPath in your driver config file only for [debugging Mobius driver app in local mode](https://github.com/Microsoft/Mobius/blob/master/notes/running-mobius-app.md#debug-mode). This will enable debugging of your C# Spark application by connecting your C# driver process from Visual Studio to the JVM process (running [CSharpRunner](https://github.com/Microsoft/Mobius/blob/master/scala/src/main/org/apache/spark/deploy/csharp/CSharpRunner.scala)) that is launched separately in an IDE (IntelliJ or Eclipse) or using sparkclr-submit script with "debug" parameter.

For normal (non-debug) execution of Apache Spark C# applications implemented using Mobius, you just need to run sparkclr-submit script without enabling debug switches (CSharpBackendPortNumber and CSharpWorkerPath) in the driver config file. You can find instructions to run a Mobius application at [getting-started page](https://github.com/Microsoft/Mobius#getting-started). The instructions cover running Mobius in standalone and YARN clusters in Windows and Linux.

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to directories pointed by %TEMP% and %TMP% environment variables? Mobius uses java.io.tmpdir to write a temporary zip file containing artifacts needed to run Mobius driver app. If you do not have permissions to write to java.io.tmpdir (that is the environment variables mentioned above) you might get the error you observed